# Position sticky iPhone flickering

Tags: html, css

Following a little piece of my code. Just wondering to know why the "iphone" cell is flickering from iphone only. PS. I can't use a table or a list for the structure. I also tried using `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` .

Basically I need the first cell to be sticky both for Left and Top on iPhone and iPad too. I would like to do that using HTML and CSS only.

> IMPORTANT

Please, do not answer with **fixed** solutions, I don't know where the table will be placed in the body. There will be an header, some content, etc etc.

```css
.table {
  width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.tr {
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tc {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.trh {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tc.first {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr trh">
    <div class="tc first">Iphone</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
    <div class="tc">value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc first">a set</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
    <div class="tc">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this code snippet with an actual iPhone? because it seems OK to me.

Comment: Of course I did @Sanira

Comment: Likely something to do with this: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/18469#issuecomment-427969331

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo doesn't seems to be the same problem. I mean I have a problem with a cell only, not with all.

Comment: @Vixed do you want to stick only one cell or the entire cell of the first row of table?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath entire first row and entire first col.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fight oddities with iOS vs everything else all the time.  It's usually involving stacking context issues.  It appears to me that the `position: sticky` and `left: 0` element become relative to that first row on iOS.  iOS doesn't handle stacking context the same as all the other browsers.

I've never really figured out exactly what causes this.  Technically your iPhone cell is stuck to the left even when it's scrolling because it's relative to it's parent which does not have `left: 0`. I'm assuming this has to do with how iOS handles `position: sticky`.  Sticky starts relative and then changes to fixed. All the other browsers at that point would make it stick to the left.  You have a `position: sticky;` element inside a `position: sticky;` element.  That is a new stacking context.  I believe iOS makes it fixed to it's parent and not the way you would expect.  Since the parent row doesn't have `left: 0` it's going to scroll with everything else.  I hope this helps.  I saw no flickering, but I had a few broken components in my company's web framework after iOS 13 came out involving scrolling and stacking contexts.  I would test on multiple iOS devices.

**edit** after playing around some more with it, I'm confident it is a stacking context issue.  I cranked the z-index up to 1000 on the iphone cell only and the rows below STILL appear above it.

[image]

If you don't have to support internet explorer I would use CSS grids to achieve this layout. Then you won't have to worry about `position: sticky`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/using-css-grid-the-right-way/

I use it for dynamic data heavy content in business applications so it can be incredibly flexible if leveraged properly.

**Updated Again** -- If you can't change the DOM at all then you're going to have to deal with the flickering as even the grid solution will require wrappers around some elements.  Just to **clarify**.... With a grid solution you DO NOT need to know how many columns or rows you will have.  You seem hung up on that aspect.  Grid areas also create a new stacking context and make everything relative to the grid area that it's in while allowing flexible units.  I cannot give you an answer until you show how your dynamic data is coming in.  We need more context to give you a code solution.

Again, the flickering is happening because you have a sticky positioned element inside another sticky element.  That's just iOS and if you want to use it like this, you will have to just deal with it.

Here's documentation about stacking contexts and how they work.  As I stated in a comment, you are going to have to take a different approach or just deal with it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Also --

Hide the overflow on your HTML and Body.  Put a wrapper around the table.  Put `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` on the wrapper.  Run it on iOS 12 and you will see it not flicker.  You won't have momentum scrolling though.  iOS13 removed the need for the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` so you can't even override it.  If you put the value of `touch` on `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` you will now get flickering. Run this code below and you'll see it not flicker.  Long story short, as I've said many times you WILL have to find a different approach.  You can't fix this now that iOS13 is out and you really wouldn't have wanted to disable momentum scrolling anyways.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.tr {
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tc {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.trh {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tc.first {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="table">
          <div class="tr trh">
            <div class="tc first">Iphone</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
            <div class="tc">value</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="tc first">a set</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
            <div class="tc">0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use "grid" since the number of rows and the columns are dynamic. If I'll use grid then I'll have to manage it with some JS and I can't.

Comment: You can use it with dynamic content. I do it every day. If I get time today I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: CSS grids will make what is called implicit grid tracks and the content will be placed along the explicit template you define. I've done some crazy stuff with dynamic layouts using it.

Comment: I don't know the number of columns. The width it's not 100vw, but more and more!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on whether you need to support IE or not.  Now I can spend the time to show you.

Comment: How is your data coming in? Where are your for loops? That will affect how this is layed out. You're going to run into these same problems on iOS using multiple position sticky properties because as I said in my answer, the new stacking contexts being made.

Comment: I'm trying to help you. It's a component yes, but somehow your data has to be coming in with a for loop or something.

Comment: as you see it, it is.

Comment: Alright.  There's nothing dynamic about your content in the context of what you have shown.  Good luck.  I'm not sure if you actually read everything in my answer, but why it's flickering is in there.

Comment: Brett thanks a lot! Makes a bit of game while scrolling, but that's ok!

Comment: @Vixed, this won't work on iOS 13 which will be the majority of iOS users.